# how to decode requests from fiddler

Tags: decode

i monitored the traffic of an app with fiddler.

The app sends some requests to the server.
This requests should contain a device ID and the current firmeware version of the device
But for only this information the request is much to big.

Here are tow requests i recorded:
example 1:
`Cl1YuDjQu+tK3K1S+A1gevyMuL2orViK3ViK3T8yuW8qsmHwuT8k2T8y5THv3T5i2msisvtl2mNW5m2rtKkrtWLxrnVlu+2rtMZrtM/v2mOl3T8y2Mtk5MIrtKkrtX2ZuvyIBaLluLiK3ViK2Gsi5DtlsG8k5mBVsGsksmtyuMuWsmHxuMjMsmuV5v/w2TLV2mrqujiKF0tdtW1huaQK3K1S+A1irWPQBD2o0O7rtMZrtMtk5T5k2MJi5TJo+Atd+A1Qu+uZsvLDu+1mpDPg+Atz+Atx6Msg5LiK6jiKunLvpD2V0O7rtMZrtV8o3G/l2GNsLVNu+A1PtXo=`

example 2:
`Cl1YuDjQu+tK3K1S+A1gevyMuL2orViK3ViKunuIuTrvuWLW5D1M2TQkuMVV5GuI5vuW3D5w5GQkuTVrtKkrtWLxrnVlu+2rtMZrtM/v2mOl3Tsi3T8y5mBrtKkrtX2ZuvyIBaLluLiK3ViK5mHy3n2M2v/q5MtouG/v3GJi5GtisGsy2Mtksmsm2TuVuWsosGHq5jiKF0tdtW1huaQK3K1S+A1irWPQBD2o0O7rtMZrtMtk5T5k2MJi5TJo+Atd+A1Qu+uZsvLDu+1mpDPg+Atz+Atx6Msg5LiK6jiKunLvpD2V0O7rtMZrtV8o3G/l2GBG7OIG+A1PtXo=`

example 1 was for device id: T491250XVPY
example 2 was for device id: T491257SEHS

I would like to know which additional informations are send to the server.
How could i decode the data send to the server?

I allready tried to decode it with base64 and urldecode but the results does not contain the device ids.